# How to make screen elements invisible/disabled based on onscreen values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC newbie question: I want to make certain screen elements - or a group thereof - either invisible or disabled based on the value of a drop-down list, checkbox, etc. on the same View.  Should all be client-side.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to check the value of the dropdown on change and then show/hide the elements as you require.

```
$('#mySelectList').change(function(){
   // Show/Hide items here.
   $('.elemsToShow').show();
   $('.elemsToHide').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable:

```
$('.select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To enable:

```
$('.select').removeAttr('disabled');
```